# How do I link Apache Superset and SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-superset, pymssql

For database I chose 'other', and I used the correct URI, I installed pymssql. I had it in the requirements-local.txt in the docker folder.

I also tried pyodbc. I checked about everything I could. I always get this error:

> ERROR: Could not load database driver: MssqlEngineSpec

Can anybody help me?

Also some of my imports don't seem to work:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_DB
from flask_caching.backends.base import BaseCache
```

I just want to connect the db to superset.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around it by replacing the usual superset part in the docker-compose.yml file with the following code:

```
 superset:
env_file: docker/.env
image: *superset-image
container_name: superset_app
# command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app"]
command: bash -c "pip install pymssql && /app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh app"
restart: unless-stopped
```